# AWS codedeploy: parallel or concurrent deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, concurrency

I'm currently experimenting with AWS codedeploy and noticed that there can be only one deployment running **at the same time**.

I have six applications (in the AWS codedeploy sense) each with one deployment group "dev". When queuing a deployment for all six applications they all run **one after another** even though they all have their own deployment group and could run in parallel.

In the [documentation about codedeploy limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/limits.html) there is a mentioning of

> Maximum number of concurrent deployments to a deployment group: 1

I then though that maybe the deployment group name was the problem since it was always the same (`dev`).

To my surprise changing the deployment group name hasn't fixed that and the deployments ran one after another as before when I had only one deployment group.

I searched and found no information regarding that limit anywhere.

Can you help me to clarify this? Thanks!

I think it is strange to have to wait such a long time when deploying independent services ("applications").

ps. Could someone please tag this question with `code-deploy` or `aws-code-deploy`. I'm too new to do it :)

Comment: I dont think we need a separate tag for each AWS service. We already have too many.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm back again with an answer (for me at least).

The reason why the deployments didn't run in parallel were that we ran into a limit of instances being provisioned **at the same time**:

[image: aws error message]

This was totally unclear when just watching the codedeploy console.

So we had 10 instances before starting a deploy and then of cause codedeploy can only do it one instance at a time.
This also means doing it one deployment at a time :)

We increased that limit and now are able to deploy in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one group of instance that you're deploying to through multiple Deployment Groups? Or do the Deployment Groups have independent instances?

If the DGs are deploying to the same instance I wouldn't be surprised if the deployments were serialised. However if you've got separate DGs working with independent EC2s I would expect that they would deploy in parallel.

Comment: We deploy to separate autoscaling groups/target groups using blue/green deployment.